# How to fix "Google Play Services won't run unless you update it"?

Tags: google-play-services, sony-xperia-z

My device is a Sony Xperia Z and it's running Android  5.0.2. It prompted me to update my Google Play Services, and when I followed the notification it delegated me to the Play Store to update it. However it would seem it is already updated.

My current version of Google Play Services is 7.8.93.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: screenshot]

The notification keeps coming back and I can't seem to find a solution. How do I get rid of this notification permanently?

Here's a look at the notification :

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: Screen Shot 2]

Comment: I see this quite often. In my case, it always helped to 1) switch back to the list of your apps, then 2) tap the app to update again (in very rare cases, repeat 1+2 again). This usually makes the "Open" button turn into "Update". Does that work for you? On the other hand, if just this app is affected: it usually auto-updates itself, so it might be you're just not fast enough :) Check which version is installed *now*, and then check again after the next update pops in (updates are quite frequent here).

Comment: When you refer to "list of your apps" do you mean going to the play store and then navigating to the my apps tab? If so Google Play Services is not listed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Didn't check for *play services* there yet as I had no need, but neither did I get any update notifications for it: that app just updates itself without asking me – which is why I suggested checking the version numbers (in *Settings › Apps › All*).

Comment: OK. Check again when your issue happens the next time. I bet it then already has updated itself – so your issue would be "how to get rid of those useless notifications". Please verify, and then [edit] your question accordingly (also include the Android version running on your device then).

Comment: It's a simple notification. Unlock the screen, go to notification bar, tap and hold that notification and choose a bell icon with a slanted line on it.

Comment: Alternatively, go to "Settings -> Apps -> All apps -> Google Play Services" -> uncheck "Show notifications".

Comment: That could work but only hides the problem. But will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

`Settings > Apps > Google Play Services > Notification settings > off`

`Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Notification settings > off`

That's it.

Comment: Since the question body also mentioned "*How do I get rid of this notification permanently?*", this answered that question, though as [the OP has commented](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116432/how-to-fix-google-play-services-wont-run-unless-you-update-it#comment145011_116432) before, "*That could work but only hides the problem*".

Answer (score 0):

Each time I have reset my phone, exactly the same thing happens. I cannot update individually only Google Play Services as it goes into an infinite loop of popups saying that you cannot Update until you Update.

The solution which worked every time is to go to the Google Play Store into the *Apps and Games* (sometimes called differently depending on the version) and doing a *Update All*. Obviously, it may update more than you want but that is the only reliable way that worked on Android 7.0. Hopefully, this can work (or some similar steps) for your version too.

Answer (score -1):

No 'guru' here, running LG tablet w/Android v5.0.2, updated software yesterday and was unable to 'update' Play Services, altho I was constantly reminded to do so.  Finally, for some reason, I decided to move Play Services App button to a different location and, when I did, it updated automatically and (I hope!) OK. Notification is gone.

Comment: That's nonsense :D

Comment: I think you're likely confusing coincidence with causality.